# I do not understand a way of proving the correctness of the algorithm to compute the Strongly Connected Components

Tags: graphs, depth-first-search, connected-components

"Introduction to algorithms" also known as CLRS, proves the correctness of the algorithm to compute the Strongly Connected Components in two ways, one of which is

> Here is another way to look at how the second depth-first search operates. Consider the component graph $(G^T)^{SCC}$ of $G^T$. If we map each strongly connected
> component visited in the second depth-first search to a vertex of $(G^T)^{SCC}$, the second depth-first search visits vertices of $(G^T)^{SCC}$ in the reverse of a topologically
> sorted order. If we reverse the edges of $(G^T)^{SCC}$, we get the graph $((G^T)^{SCC})^T$.
> Because $((G^T)^{SCC})^T = G^{SCC}$, the second depth-first search
> visits the vertices of $G^{SCC}$in topologically sorted order.

The algorithm is:

1. Execute DFS on $G$ (starting at an arbitrary starting vertex), keeping track of the ﬁnishing times of all vertices.
2. Compute the transpose,
3. Execute DFS on $G^T$, starting at the vertex with the latest ﬁnishing time, forming a tree rooted at that vertex. Once a tree is completed, move on to the unvisited vertex with the next latest ﬁnishing time and form another tree using DFS and repeat until all the vertices in $G^T$ are visited.
4. Output the vertices in each tree formed by the second DFS as a separate strongly connected component.

Might I ask you what the quoted block of text mean? Thank you in advance.

Comment: what part in the quotes, you did not understand? Did you try with some examples?

Comment: Honestly? I understood nothing XD

Comment: I'm afraid "please explain this paragraph to me" is not a good fit for this format, as it's unclear what you did understand and didn't understand; it might be asking too much; and I'm concerned if someone explained in different language you might just say you didn't understand that, either.  This is a question-and-answer site, and it is designed for specific, narrowly focused questions.  So asking a specific question about that section of text might be appropriate, but just asking someone to explain the whole thing isn't.  As suggested, trying some examples is often a good way to understand.

Comment: @inuyasha-yagami I am sorry. So, What does "mapping each strongly connected component visited in the second depth-first search to a vertex of $(G^T)^{SCC}$ mean? Thank you very much.